# Return List<String> or String in hibernate query without query annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I am using Spring Boot application. I am using following method to return `List<String>` using *@Query*

annotation.

```
@Query("select c.name from Customer c")
List<String> findAllNames();
```

Is there a way to get the above result without @Query or @NativeQuery annotations?

Comment: use prepare statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Spring Data JPA](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-jpa) supports this quite well. You can define a POJO that represents the (reduced) object (the projection) you want of the entity, then [define a method that describes the query](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods), returns the appropriate type, and Spring Data will generate all the code necessary to execute the query and map the results.

Here's an example of a custom repository interface that uses this technique (untested pseudo-code):

```java
public class CustomerSummary {
    private String name;
    // constructor and getters
}

@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {
    List<CustomerSummary> getAllSummaries();
}
```

I'm not sure if you can use "simple" types such as `String` in the return type, but I wouldn't be surprised if that is supported.

Also, you might have to tweak the exact method naming of `` to make sure Spring Data correctly interprets it as you want. [Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords) is some additional reference documentation.

Comment: Is it possible to convert List<CustomerSummary> to List<String>?

Comment: That solution is not an adequate replacement. I would still go with the @Query to safe the extra cost of an extra interface and extra call to the function to get the customer name.

Answer (score 1):

You could use projection to select only `name` property:

```
interface CustomerNameProjection {
   String getName();
}
```

and then use it in `Repository` class:

```
List<CustomerNameProjection> findAllProjectedBy();
```

edit: corrected repository method name

Comment: I get following error.

'findAll()' in 'com.sample.repository.CustomerRepository' clashes with 'findAll()' in 'org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository'; attempting to use incompatible return type

Comment: Right, that name is normally taken in repository. You can go with `findAllProjectedBy()` method name

Answer (score 0):

Inject EntityManager and call [createQuery](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createQuery-java.lang.String-).

```
entityManager.createQuery("select c.name from Customer c")
    .getResultList()
```